# Gulp compiling files to dest folder and src folder

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

My gulpfile is adding the compiled css and js files to both the dest (css / js) folders and the src (scss / coffee) folders.

The desired outcome is that the compiled files **only** print to the **dest folders**.

This is only happening when running gulp on Windows and not on Mac. Also, if I run the tasks without the watch, it compiles correctly; 'gulp styles' compiles the css files only to the css folder - 'gulp scripts' compiles the js files only to the js folder.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(['scss/**/*.scss'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('coffee/**/*.coffee')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", ['styles']);
    gulp.watch("coffee/**/*.coffee", ['scripts']);
});
```

Comment: Locally, I tried to replicating this issue on windows but was unable to.  My `node_modules` directory was in the same directory as the `coffee` and `scss` folders. What version of Windows, npm, and gulp are you currently using? Also are you possibly using a global version of gulp?

Comment: Windows 7 - Latest versions of both node (5.6.0) and npm (3.6.0) - node_modules / coffee / scss folds should all be in the same directory, you are correct. Gulp is installed globally as it is necessary if you want to run gulp - what do you mean using that version? (the global and project level gulp are the same version).

Comment: if you install gulp globally (`npm install -g gulp`, installs to `<drive>/Users/<you>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules`) you could be running a different version than running gulp locally (`<project dir>/node_modules`). Just looking for a possible version disparity when compared to your mac version.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and that's what I mean by they are both same version of gulp (3.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `gulp.dest` twice once before minification and once after minification. Calling dest writes file to disk on the path provided.

If you just want minified versions

**For Css**

```
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
      .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
```

**For Js**

```
pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
      .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue - it now just copies the single file to both folders

Comment: What is your dest folder path,where you want to put the files?

Comment: css/ and js/
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))

Answer (score 0):

You possibly could try adding a `.` to the destination paths to help preserve the source path:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('css/')) -> .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
```

and

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('js/')) -> .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'))
```

Comment: Still doesn't affect the version being created in the src path.